# How to find reason for rollback during rollback works in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, rollback

Working on Oracle 12.c, I have a situation, that a big transaction performs a rollback, which takes several hours. I see the status of the session e.g. in V$SESSION.MESSAGE "Transaction Rollback: xid:0x0011.017.001a889d : 862496 out of 1640941 Blocks done".

However, I would like to know the reason (SQL-Errorcode) before the rollback is finished to be able to work on the solution.
Right now, I get the errorcode as result after rollback has finished.
Is there a chance to see it in advance?

Comment: Do you have access to the alert log on the server?

Comment: If you have purchased the Diagnostic and tuning pack licences, you can produce a SQL Live Monitor Report for the sql_id and sql_exec_id for your session - that will include the error message if it failed.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: No, only to `V$DIAG_ALERT_EXT`. But it logs mainly DB driven causes like _out of space_ issues.

Comment: @AndrewSayer : License is available, but isn't there any more easy way to directly get this particular information? Maybe somewhere in context of the transaction?

Comment: Why can't you work on a solution with the error code you get after the rollback?

Comment: Just because of time saving. Waiting hours (even on Exadata) to get the error code is serial working.
Knowing the reason allows preparing for the next iteration and start processing immediately after rollback. If I see a problem, that I could solve myself, it might be worth waiting, otherwise I can left my Computer in the evening during rollback ;-)

Comment: And you have no way to communicate with the DBA?

Comment: I have, but they don't know either. In my case, it was an application driven exception, that wasn't logged in alert.log.
And, it's a quite unusual question. That's why I'm asking here...